# Let $(R, +, \cdot)$ be a finite ring without zero divisors, show that $R$ has a neutral element for $\cdot$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

I have to prove the question in the title, but I am having some difficulties.

Here's a sketch what I've already tried:

Choose $a \in R$.
Because $R$ is finite, there exist positive integers $i$ and $j$ ($i\neq j$) so that $a^i = a^j \Leftrightarrow a^ia = a^ja \Leftrightarrow a^ia - a^ja = 0 \Leftrightarrow a^j(a^{i-j}a - a) = 0$.

Because $R$ doesn't have any zero divisors and $a^j \neq 0$, we must have $a^{i-j}a - a = 0$ and thus, $a^{i-j}a = a$.

So now I think that $a^{i-j}$ is the neutral element for $\cdot$ but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: If $R$ is a finite ring with no zero divisors, than what does the group of units look like?

Comment: woops i made a typo, I meant the neutral element for the multiplication. I corrected it

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more clear. If we know that there are no zero divisors, what can we say about the group of units of $R$? The issue that I see with your proof right now is that you still need to show that $a^{i-j}b = b$ for any $b \in R$ and that might be difficult (but not impossible)

Comment: Also, what definition are you using for the ring?

Comment: I don't know what we could say about the group of units, so you'll have to help me there.
The definition we're using is that $R, +$ is a commutative group and that $\cdot$ is associative and distributive (over $+$).

Comment: Ah okay, that's different than what I thought you were using. Makes sense now, I believe you are starting from a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra) rng and proving that if it has no zero divisors then it is in fact a ring

Comment: Yeah okay, then our professor does it a bit different I suppose. So how would I be able to prove that if a finite 'rng' has no zero divisors, then it has a neutral element for $\cdot$? I think I was on the right track

Comment: The linked duplicates *title* says commutative, but inside the question it also asks about the noncommutative case, and the solutions address it.

Comment: @rschwieb that didn't pop up though when i searched it, even the commutative case

Comment: @O22 I searched "finite divisor identity" and it was the second hit for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at this point, you have $a^{i-j}a = a$. We want to show that $a^{i-j}$ is in fact the identity element for $\cdot$. Now, this amounts to saying that for any $b \in R$, $a^{i-j}\cdot b = b$. So we have the following:

$a^{i-j} \cdot b = c 
\iff a \cdot a^{i-j} \cdot b = a \cdot c 
\iff a^{i-j}a \cdot b = a \cdot c 
\iff ab = ac $.

But since we have no zero divisors, this means that $b = c$.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, if it isn't understandable I'll edit to clarify, just let me know!

Comment: Formatting is great, thanks a bunch!

Comment: No worries! There may be some small details that need cleaning up before submitting the proof (like stating that $a \neq 0$ for example) but I believe this is the core of the argument

Comment: Yeah I stated in my actual proof that $a \neq 0$. Are there any other small details you're thinking of?

Comment: That was the main concern that I had!